# Sharing resources between workers in a message queue setup

Tags: multithreading, architecture, rabbitmq, distributed-system

I'm trying to understand if the following is possible with message brokers and queues:

Let's say I have a queue of tasks to be performed by a worker on a resource.

I have full control over the number of workers. For the sake of an example, there'll be 2 of them.

Tasks operate on a single resource. I have little control over the number of those resources, I just know that some tasks will apply to the same resource. The number of resources is many times lower than the number of tasks. But generally, I cannot start as many workers as there are resources.

Let's say there's 10 resources total. While a task is operating on a resource, other workers should not start tasks operating on the same resource.

Can this somehow be organized with celery or rabbitmq?
Maybe my way of thinking about it is wrong.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is usually called a 'distributed lock'. It's probably easier to use redis or a database for the lock state and the queues for communication. See: https://martin.kleppmann.com/2016/02/08/how-to-do-distributed-locking.html

Answer (score 0):

One thing I have been considering is adding another broker to the whole picture.

So broker subscribes to the original task queue and sends messages to workers. But before sending a message it checks if the resource is already busy. If so, the task is requeened with a delay.

Resource states can be in a global variable, workers themselves don't need to care about them.

Broker additionally has to listen to acks from workers and free resource locks accordingly.

Does this make sense? That broker will not scale of course, but I can later put resource states into Redis to work around that.